# creating an excel add-in

Tags: vba, excel

can someone please get me started on the following:

i would like to package an excel macro as an add-in to excel. the macro will reside on a central computer, where 10 other computers will connect to.

how do i create an add-in that will be constantly updated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/07/29/conditionally-load-excel-add-ins/) you can have an Add-In reside on a network share, so you wouldn't even need to bootstrap and update the code via code.  Here's a quick [rundown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140936%28office.10%29.aspx) on how to create an Add-In.